# how to create editable dropdownlist in mvc4 razor?

Tags: razor

Hello everyone I am trying to create an editable dropdownlist in mvc4 razor. but how can i create Editable DropDownList in mvc4 razor?

I need exactly like this examples http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/ and http://www.igniteui.com/combo/overview

I tried above sample but it is not working correctly.

Help me someone.